# ShakeService.java not printing Log message after calling it through intent

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to call ShackService.java through intent when switch turned on which detect the acceleration of mobile when it will shake and show Toast message but it is not working so what is the problem in my code?

I already tried to change the position of that part of calling intent and also get Log message in that part of the code which is working fine but Log message did not obtain in ShackService.java after calling intent.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.safetyapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Switch OnOffSwitch;
    private Boolean SwitchState;

    private EditText messagebox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        messagebox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messagebox);

        OnOffSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.OnAndOffSwitch);       
//Initialize switch
        SwitchState = OnOffSwitch.isChecked();                  //Current state of switch

        if (SwitchState == false) {                                      //to show initial text
            OnOffSwitch.setText("Service is Off");
        }

        OnOffSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String emergencymessage = messagebox.getText().toString().trim();
                if (emergencymessage.isEmpty()) {
                    OnOffSwitch.setChecked(false);
                    OnOffSwitch.setText("Service is Off");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message Box cannot leave empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    if (OnOffSwitch.isChecked()) {

                        //start shake detection
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShakeService.class);
                        //Start Service
                        startService(intent);

                        OnOffSwitch.setText("Service is On");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service starts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        OnOffSwitch.setText("Service is Off");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ShakeService.java

```
package com.example.android.safetyapp;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class ShakeService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final String TAG = "myApp";

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private float mAccel; // acceleration apart from gravity
    private float mAccelCurrent; // current acceleration including gravity
    private float mAccelLast; // last acceleration including gravity

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI, new Handler());
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
        mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
        mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x * x + y * y + z * z));
        float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
        mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta;
        // perform low-cut filter
        if (mAccel > -1) {
            Log.v(TAG, "did something");
            Toast.makeText(ShakeService.this,"Shaking detected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mAccel=0;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to print log message "did something" after intent is calling and also "Shaking detected" when this intent is call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

register the service in manifest `<service android:name=".ShakeService"/>`